# How to traverse all the nodes in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I  am a newbie to react and currently developing an application,

***BACKGROUND:***

It has admin, faculty, student, dashboards and a static landing page with buttons to /admin/login ,/faculty/login ,/student/login. which opens respective dashboards.

***PROBLEM:***

*when I log in with student's login i am able to access all the dashboards & vice-versa, i have a field named role inside my firebase nodes,

*while logging in i check user's role and it doesn't allow other users with other roles to login ,but once after i login i am able to access all dashboards(which should not happen) including the dashboard which i am supposed to open , i am using react and routes.js, my public and private routes.

[image]

i am trying to use a isstudent,isfaculty,isadmin flags to get role and restrict the access but not able to figure out how to traverse all the nodes.

any suggestion would be helpful ,thanks in advance.

***ROUTES.js***

```
  const Routes = props => {
              if (props.user) {
                 let isStudent=false;
                 let isFaculty=false;
     let isAdmin=false;
                const uid = props.user.uid;
                const request = firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref(`student/${uid}`)
                  .once("value")
                  .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.val().role === "student") {
         // isStudent=true
                     console.log(snapshot.val());
                    }
                  });

                firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref(`faculty/${uid}`)
                  .once("value")
                  .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.val().role === "faculty") {
                      console.log(snapshot.val());
    //isFaculty=true
                    }
                  });

                firebase
                  .database()
                  .ref(`admin/${uid}`)
                  .once("value")
                  .then(snapshot => {
                    if (snapshot.val().role === "admin") {
                      console.log(snapshot.val());
    //isAdmin=true
                    }
                  });
              return (
                <MainLayout>
                  <Switch>
                    <AdminPublicRoute
                      {...props}
                      exact
                      restricted={true}
                      path="/admin/login"
                      component={AdminLogin}
                    />
                 {isAdmin&&<AdminPrivateRoute
                      {...props}
                      path="/admin/admindashboard"
                      exact
                      component={AdminDash}
                    />}
            <FacultyPublicRoute
                      {...props}
                      exact
                      restricted={true}
                      path="/faculty/login"
                      component={FacultyLogin}
                    />
 {isFaculty && <FacultyPrivateRoute
                      {...props}
                      path="/faculty/facultydashboard"
                      exact
                      component={FacultyDash}
                    />}

            <StudentPublicRoute
                      {...props}
                      exact
                      restricted={true}
                      path="/student/login"
                      component={StudentLogin}
                    />
                    {isStudent&& <StudentPrivateRoute
                      {...props}
                      path="/student/studentdashboard"
                      exact
                      component={StudentDash}
                    />}
             </Switch>
                </MainLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nicest - lodash map:

```
const roles = _.map(obj.admin, item => item.role)
```

Easiest - Object.keys

```
const roles = Object.keys(obj.admin).map(key => key.role)
```